# Chained if statements in rust?

Tags: rust

The Swift language supports multiple if statements on one line.

```
import Foundation

let x: Int? = 7

if let y = x, pow(Double(y), 2) == 49 {
    // do something
}
```

In rust I need to do

```
let x: Option<i32> = Some(7);
if let Some(y) = x {
    if y.pow(2) == 49 {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something like the Swift solution in rust?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667

Comment: Would be something for if y?.pow(2) == 49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` the operation before, and then match it fully:

```rust
if matches!(x.map(|y| y.pow(2)), Some(49)) {
    println!("Yeah");
}
```

Or using `==`:

```rust
if x.map(|y| y.pow(2)) ==  Some(49) {
    println!("Yeah");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78774df61ca5daf026e01d91952016e1)

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother with `matches!` here, and just use equality comparison instead: `if x.map(|y| y.pow(2)) == Some(49) {`.

Comment: Readability 0% ;-)

Comment: @Markus, yeah, maybe, in your opinion. Different people think differently. Feel free to edit the answer and the `==` variant too. Thanks :)